# How to declare public static byte?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a class name constants where I put all the constant values in my project. I am also checking if the server is reachable all over my project. I want to declare a ip address in my constants so that I only change one and implement it in my project. I dont know how to declare the value in my constants class. What I need is below:

> var ping = new Ping();
>               var reply = ping.Send(new IPAddress(Constants.ipaddress), 1500);

```
//I want to change 192,168,120,10 in the value in my constants
var ping = new Ping();
var reply = ping.Send(new IPAddress(new byte[] { 192, 168, 120, 10 }), 1500);

//What I declared in my constants
public static byte ipaddress;
```

Comment: public static byte[] ipaddress = new byte[] { 192, 168, 120, 10 };

Comment: @PoulBak He wants something that can't be changed.  Even a `static readonly` won't be enough, since the content of the array can be modified.

Comment: @Corey Post your answer then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you *could* do

```
public static readonly byte[] ipaddress = new byte[] { 192, 168, 120, 10 };

var ping = new Ping();
var reply = ping.Send(new IPAddress(ipaddress), 1500);
```

However, I would encourage you to instead use the *app.config* for this information. That way, you can change the address *without having to rebuild your project*. If you choose to do that, store the address in standard dotted-quad format (`"192.168.120.10"`) and use [`IPAddress.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.parse).

Comment: how to use IPAddress.parse?

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto Added a link

Comment: Will I have a problem in the future if I use byte instead of string?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "problem", but you can't store a byte array in a config file, which is why I suggested using a string.

Comment: @DStanley FYI, no `app.config` for Xamarin.iOS|Android, and changing a file in a package would include at least a re-signing.